# Is class A derived from class B

Tags: javascript

I want to know how I can determine whether class A is derived from class B in JavaScript. Here's an example, using ES6 classes for clarity:

```
class Animal
{
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
}

// ...

function makeAnimalOf(ctor)
{
    if (/* ctor derived from Animal */) {
        return new ctor;
    }
    throw "ctor is not derived from Animal";
}

var mrWoofles = makeAnimalOf(Dog);
var mittens = makeAnimalOf(Cat);
```

What would my type guard in makeAnimalOf need to look like?